# How to call a Blazor component with Typeparameters from menu with href

Tags: menu, blazor, components, type-parameter

I have a Blazor component, that implements thre type paramters like this

```
@typeparam T where T : class
@typeparam V where V : class
@typeparam P where P : class
```

I use this component like this

```
<MyComponent T="Location" V="LocationView" P="LocationParent" />
```

If I want to call this component from a menu, I wonder how can I pass the typeparam (and perhaps other parameters) to this component?

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/LocationData">Locations</a></li>
```

I added the @page "/LocationData" to the component, but how to pass typeparam and paramters?

At this time I create an empty razor component, like this

```
LocationIndex.razor
@page "/LocationIndex"
<MyComponent T="Location" V="LocationView" P="LocationParent" WhereClause="deleted eq false" />
```

And from the menu calling LocationIndex instead of LocationData directly

```
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/LocationIndex">Locations</a></li>
```

So this works fine, but is it the right way? And how can I call this directly from the menu with an href? Is this possible, and does it make sense? Or is the additional "index" component the best way?

Comment: What is the intended usage here, do you want to display the data in the menu item or navigate to another page? If you want it displayed in the menu you will need to place a `<MyComponent />` within your `<li>`; if you want to navigate to a page with the component implemented then the **LocationIndex.razor** page looks good.

Comment: Thank you, yes LocationIndex.razor works good, and it's my intention to have it work this way. I only wonder if there is a way to call this component from a menu, without going through this LocationIndex "wrapper" since it does nothing than display the (main) component ....